# Reading data in python?

Tags: python, string, file, io

I am trying to read data in Python one way I do it is like this

```
states = """
        Alabama
        Alberta
        Alaska
        Arizona
        Arkansas
        Bob
        Tom
        Ted
        William
        """
states_list = [w.strip().lower() for w in states.splitlines() if w]
```

Now if I am trying to read similar data from a file its not working. I do it like this

```
file1 = open('dictionary_file.txt','r')
data = file1.read()
file1.close()
```

and then iterate over items in the data

Here is the entire code, the related part is at the end.

```
def _get_child_branches(tree):
"""
This method return all the branches of the tree
"""
return tree[1:]


def _get_child_branch(tree, c):
"""
This method returns the specific branch of the tree given the character
"""
for branch in _get_child_branches(tree):
    if branch[0] == c:
        return branch

return None


def _retrive_branch(k, tree):
"""
This method is used for getting the branch for a given word
"""
if not k:
    return None

for c in k:
    child_branch = _get_child_branch(tree, c)
    if not child_branch:
        return None
    tree = child_branch

return tree


def _is_tree_bucket(bucket):
if len(bucket) != 2:
    return False

return type(bucket[1]) is tuple


def _get_bucket_key(bucket):
if not _is_tree_bucket(bucket):
    return None

return bucket[1][0]


def has_key(k, tree):
"""
To check if the tree containes the keyword
"""
return _retrive_branch(k, tree) is not None


def retree_val(k, tree):
key_tuple = _retrive_branch(k, tree)
if not key_tuple:
    return None

return key_tuple[1]


def insert_key(key, v, tree):
"""
Insert a (key, value) pair into tree
"""
if not key or has_key(key, tree):
    return

for char in key:
    branch = _get_child_branch(tree, char)
    if not branch:
        new_branch = [char]
        tree.append(new_branch)
        tree = new_branch
    else:
        tree = branch
tree.append((key, v))


def start_with_prefix(prefix, tree):
"""
Find words start with prefix
"""
branch = _retrive_branch(prefix, tree)
if not branch:
    return []

prefix_list = []
q = branch[1:]
while q:
    curr_branch = q.pop(0)
    if _is_tree_bucket(curr_branch):
        prefix_list.append(_get_bucket_key(curr_branch))
    else:
        q.extend(curr_branch[1:])

return prefix_list






if __name__ == "__main__":
tree = [[]]
file1 = open('dictionary_file.txt','r')
data = file1.read().split('\n')
file1.close()
states = """
        Alabama
        Alberta
        Alaska
        Arizona
        Arkansas
        Bob
        Tom
        Ted
        William"""
states_list = [w.strip().lower() for w in states.splitlines() if w]
print(states_list)
print(states)
for state in data:
    insert_key(state, True, tree)


print start_with_prefix("a", tree)
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Shouldn't triple quotes only be used for docstrings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding `.split('\n')` will resolve it.

```
file1 = open('dictionary_file.txt','r')
data = file1.read().split('\n')
file1.close()
for i in data:
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace splitlines with a [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) and iterate over that:

```
with open('dictionary_file.txt','r') as f:
   lines  =[w.strip().lower() for w in f if w]
```

There is never any need to read a whole file into memory unless you actually need the data at once, a file object is iterable and will give you each line as you iterate.

On a side note, you need  `if w` in your splitlines code as you add a newline before your lines and after, start your string at a quote and end it at a quote and you won't get any empty strings:

```
states = """Alabama
    Alberta
    Alaska
    Arizona
    Arkansas
    Bob
    Tom
    Ted
    William"""
```

Comment: I guess the last paragraph is for me. :P

Comment: @Sait, I always say it, nothing personal! So many people starting out always call readlines or read and then either split read into a list of lines or iterate over readlines  doing work they could do just iterating over the file object.

Answer (score 1):

Please just read [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

```
with open('dictionary_file.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

states_list = [w.strip().lower() for w in lines if w]
```

**Edit**: I realized there is no need to use `readlines()` here. Just use @Padraic's answer.

Comment: It doesnt work for some reason... my txt file just has just a list of words it works fine when I have them in my program but if i try doing it using file it gives error

Comment: @user2939685 It should work. What is the error you are getting? However, I think you should go with Padraic's answer, which is more elegant.

Comment: when I am printing the two they are printed like this which means there is some problem...['alabama', 'alberta', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas', 'bob', 'tom', 'ted', 'william']

            Alabama
            Alberta
            Alaska
            Arizona
            Arkansas
            Bob
            Tom
            Ted
            William

Comment: I didn't get what is the problem? Can you please update the original question with the expected input/output?

Comment: the code work if i replace data with state_list in the last for loop where i am inserting the items.